# How do you render a view in the controller?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, viewcontroller

I'm trying to make the camera pop up on a button click, but my view is not persisting because I keep getting an error:

`Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.`

I have an imageView rendered to place the picture when after it's shot, using the `ImagePickerController` function, but I'm guessing it's somehow not being pushed to the view.

Do you have any ideas?

Code that might be helpful is below:
- Basically, ViewController creates a UIView `capturebutton`, and when it is tapped, a Camera view controller is presented.

---

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{
        let rect1 = CGRectMake(100, 60, 40, 60)
        let captureButton2 = UIView(frame: rect1)
        captureButton2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        captureButton2.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("didTapImageView:")))
        scrollView.addSubview(captureButton2)

    func didTapImageView(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        let captureDetails = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier
         ("CameraVC")! as? CameraVC3
        presentViewController(captureDetails!, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

**CameraViewController**

```
class CameraVC3: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate{

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){
            var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    var photoImageView2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(40, 120, 200, 200))

    // handles output
    func ImagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
         photoImageView2.image = image
         picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it! I needed to add a line in my `viewDidLoad()` fn

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(photoImageView)
}
```